# How to append to my list?

Tags: python

I have the following program:

```
for stmt in irsb.statements:
 if isinstance(stmt, pyvex.IRStmt.WrTmp):
   tmp = stmt.tmp
   print tmp
```

tmp provides different output for each statements when printing. The output is like this:

```
t0 = GET:I64(offset=56)
4
t4 = GET:I64(offset=48)
3
```

at which 3 and 4 are output of tmp. I want all of these numbers to be appended into a list for comparison. Moreover, I want a 't' letter to be added to them when printing. I tried the following

```
tmp = 't{}'.format(tmp)
a =[]
for  val in enumerate(tmp):
 a.append(val)
```

and the output is like the following:

```
[(0, 't')]
[(0, 't'), (1, '0')]
t0
t0 = GET:I64(offset=56)
[(0, 't')]
[(0, 't'), (1, '4')]
t4
t4 = GET:I64(offset=48)
[(0, 't')]
[(0, 't'), (1, '3')]
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *it did not work*? What was the actual, what is the expected output?

Comment: What's the error you get? IT should be .append() with ()

Comment: `append` uses round braces, so `a.append(val)`. Also, you can just do `for  val in tmp:`. I don't know whether those two changes alone are sufficient to make this work as there isn't much detail given.

Comment: Isn't `tmp` a string based on `tmp = 't{}'.fotmat(tmp)`? Why would you want to enumerate a string?

Comment: @roganjosh "curly braces" == `{ }` I think you wanted "round brackets or braces". Sorry for the minor correction :(

Comment: `( )` is called parenthesis or parens for short.

Comment: The output is like this:[(0, 't')]
[(0, 't'), (1, '0')]
t0
t0 = GET:I64(offset=56)
[(0, 't')]
[(0, 't'), (1, '4')]
t4
t4 = GET:I64(offset=48)
[(0, 't')]
[(0, 't'), (1, '3')]
t3
t3 = Sub64(t4,0x0000000000000008)
PUT(offset=48) = t3
STle(t3) = t0
PUT(offset=184) = 0x0000000000400401
------ IMark(0x400401, 7, 0) ------
[(0, 't')]
[(0, 't'), (1, '5')]

Comment: Edit your question to include the output you get.

Comment: t is seperated from the integer number and nothing has been appended

Answer (score 1):

your code:

```
tmp = 't{}'.format(tmp)
a =[]
for  val in enumerate(tmp):
 a.append[val]
```

makes very little sense.

I think what you want is

```
a = []
for stmt in irsb.statements:
 if isinstance(stmt, pyvex.IRStmt.WrTmp):
   tmp = stmt.tmp
   print 't{}'.format(tmp)
   a.append(tmp)
```

did I guess right?

Comment: he said >I want a 't' letter to be added to them when printing /> which I took to mean he wanted it to display with a t but use the int value, but yes, it could easily be either. :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. The code OP posted misled me to think differently.

Comment: I am stopped with error: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
using the above code

Comment: @user3126804 none of the code I have added to your question includes iterating over anything - could you post the code your run that gives you that error?